# How to fix html ordered list?

Tags: html, css

I converted docx file to html file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KYR_lvl6YySKAvgzzg8JPhCc9G5S-_dL/view?usp=sharing  -- full html code

I the html file i have this

```
1.            Предмет договора
```

But I want to have

```
1. Предмет договора
```

How can I fix this code

```
<ol style='margin-top:0cm' start=1 type=1>
 <li class=MsoNormal style='margin-right:2.15pt;text-align:center'><b><span
     style='font-size:12.0pt;letter-spacing:-.3pt'>Предмет договора.</span></b></li>
</ol>
```

[image]

Comment: remove `text-align: center;`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `text-align:center` on the `li` that's positioning it that way. If you don't want that then just remove it. The code would look something like this:

```
<ol style='margin-top:0cm' start=1 type=1>
 <li class=MsoNormal style='margin-right:2.15pt'><b><span
     style='font-size:12.0pt;letter-spacing:-.3pt'>Предмет договора.</span></b></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `text-align:center` from `<li class=MsoNormal style='margin-right:2.15pt;text-align:center'>`.

Before:

```
<ol style='margin-top:0cm' start=1 type=1>
 <li class="MsoNormal" style='margin-right:2.15pt;text-align:center'><b><span
     style='font-size:12.0pt;letter-spacing:-.3pt'>Предмет договора.</span></b></li>
</ol>
```

After:

```
<ol style='margin-top:0cm' start=1 type=1>
 <li class=MsoNormal style='margin-right:2.15pt;'><b><span
     style='font-size:12.0pt;letter-spacing:-.3pt'>Предмет договора.</span></b></li>
</ol>
```